System.ArgumentNullException on new MutexAccessRule
I have a "single application instance" detection function, using the "classic" Mutex approach:
var identity = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(identity, MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
var securitySettings = new MutexSecurity();
securitySettings.AddAccessRule(allowEveryoneRule);
var mutex = new Mutex(true, __MUTEX_ID, out createdNew);
mutex.SetAccessControl(securitySettings);

It was working fine until now. 
Recently, I started to get a System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'identity')' on the new MutexAccessRule line.
Strange enough, the identity value is NOT null. I tried also creating the identity with this ctors without success:
identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner;

identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner.AccountDomainSid;

identity = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinDomainSid, null);

identity = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.NTAuthoritySid, null);

And also this ways failed:
string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(user, MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

... or ...
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
var acct = sid.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)) as NTAccount;
var allowEveryoneRule = new MutexAccessRule(acct.ToString(), MutexRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);

I suspect the failure started after the last System.Security.Principal.Windows package update, but now I'm unable to install the older version...

same problem here, on .net 6. when I look up source code, it shows not supported: https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.AccessControl/artifacts/obj/System.Threading.AccessControl/Debug/net10.0/System.Threading.AccessControl.notsupported.cs,53 (but actually crashes in base constructor and shows wrong exception)
